# Unable to intersect a shapefile with a set of points

Tags: qgis, vector, geoprocessing, intersection, accuracy

I have a set of 1000 urban points that I'm trying to intersect with a classification result to find the accuracy but I keep getting an error
"GEOS geoprocessing error: One or more input features have invalid geometry."

Answer (score 1):

Double check your feature table to make sure that all of features have geometry/shape data associated with them.

[To help with this you may want to download the Geometry Checker Plugin.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html)

[And also check this GISSE Question for other options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/fixing-geometry-validity-errors-in-qgis)

If all features appear valid, have you tried resetting the CRS?

[From this Q&A:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26008/ftools-error-invalid-geometry)

> Reset the CRS. Go to Settings>Project Properties> CRS and Set a
>   Reference system again. This should do the job. If not, export it as
>   an ESRI shapefile.

Comment: All the features are valid, and yes I tried resetting the CRS and it didn't work, but I tried on a different version of qgis and it worked fine, I don't know the reason though. I was using QGIS 2.18.11 then the one that worked is qgis 2.8.2

Comment: Early versions of QGIS 2.18 had a whole suite of bugs related to invalid geometry error showing up despite geometry being completely valid. Your issue sounds like a similar bug, which you can report here: https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues