# Intersecting to vector layers when there is no common attribute

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, geoprocessing, intersection

I am trying to join two vector layers into one, the first is a road noise barrier shapefile, the second is a vectorised DEM. 
The road barriers have a relative height attribute for each section of road, one barrier passes through several DEM regions while maintaining the same relative height.

When running the intersect operation I get the following error: GEOS geoprocessing error: One or more input features have invalid geometry.

How can I fix this error or get around the problem another way to find the height of the barrier after subtracting the Local DEM.

[image: Zoom in image showing the single line traversing many areas]

**Changing the CRS didn't solve the problem**

Comment: Use the buffer tool on your vector layer and apply a buffer of 0.

Comment: @julsbreakdown thanks for comment, it didn't work with a 0 distance buffer but a very small one did the job. I believe it is because the area of the line is zero.

Answer (score 1):

To correct the error I would suggest you try this [fTools-Error: “…invalid geometry…”](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26008/ftools-error-invalid-geometry):

> Reset the CRS. Go to Settings > Project Properties > CRS and Set a Reference system again. This should do the job. If not, export it as an ESRI shapefile.